# NOT IN clause within an IIF within the WHERE clause

Tags: t-sql

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [Aftermarket].[ft_Filter_V41_HubAssembly_AxleStudThreads_DEV] (
    @SearchTokens                    dbo.SearchTokenTableType      READONLY,
    @AftermarketHubAssemblyNumbers   dbo.ConMetPartNumberTableType READONLY,
    @TruckCompartmentIds             dbo.IntegerTableType          READONLY,
    @TruckMakeIds                    dbo.IntegerTableType          READONLY,
    @AxleNameIds                     dbo.IntegerTableType          READONLY,
    @GrossAxleWeightRatingRangeIds   dbo.IntegerTableType          READONLY,
    @AxleStudThreadIds               dbo.IntegerTableType          READONLY,
    @WheelMaterialStudLengthClassIds dbo.IntegerTableType          READONLY,
    @HubCastingMaterialTypeIds       dbo.IntegerTableType          READONLY,
    @HubAssemblyTypeIds              dbo.IntegerTableType          READONLY,
    @ExcludeProvidedValues BIT = 1
)
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN
    SELECT DISTINCT v.AxleStudThreadId AS Id,
    CASE v.AxleStudThreadId WHEN 0 THEN N'—' ELSE th.ThreadDesignation END AS Designation,
    bt.DiameterValue AS DiameterInch,
    CASE v.AxleStudThreadId WHEN 0 THEN N'—'
                            WHEN 6 THEN N'3/4'
                            WHEN 8 THEN N'5/8'
                            ELSE th.ThreadDesignation
                            END AS NominalDiameter
    FROM Aftermarket.vFilters_V3_HubAssemblies AS v
    JOIN Stud.Threads AS th ON v.AxleStudThreadId = th.Id
    JOIN Stud.BaseThreads AS bt ON th.BaseThreadId = bt.Id
    WHERE (((SELECT COUNT(PartNumber) FROM @AftermarketHubAssemblyNumbers)   = 0) OR v.HubAssemblyNumber                  IN (SELECT PartNumber FROM @AftermarketHubAssemblyNumbers ))
      AND (((SELECT COUNT(Value)      FROM @TruckCompartmentIds)             = 0) OR v.TruckCompartmentId                 IN (SELECT Value FROM @TruckCompartmentIds                ))
      AND (((SELECT COUNT(Value)      FROM @TruckMakeIds)                    = 0) OR v.TruckMakeId                        IN (SELECT Value FROM @TruckMakeIds                       ))
      AND (((SELECT COUNT(Value)      FROM @AxleNameIds)                     = 0) OR v.AxleNameId                         IN (SELECT Value FROM @AxleNameIds                        ))
      AND (((SELECT COUNT(Value)      FROM @GrossAxleWeightRatingRangeIds)   = 0) OR v.GawrRangeId                        IN (SELECT Value FROM @GrossAxleWeightRatingRangeIds      ))

      AND (((SELECT COUNT(Value) FROM @AxleStudThreadIds) = 0) OR IIF(@ExcludeProvidedValues = 1,
                                                                            v.AxleStudThreadId NOT IN (SELECT Value FROM @AxleStudThreadIds),
                                                                            v.AxleStudThreadId IN (SELECT Value FROM @AxleStudThreadIds))
                                                                      )

      AND (((SELECT COUNT(Value)      FROM @WheelMaterialStudLengthClassIds) = 0) OR v.WheelMaterialStudLengthClassId     IN (SELECT Value FROM @WheelMaterialStudLengthClassIds    ))
      AND (((SELECT COUNT(Value)      FROM @HubCastingMaterialTypeIds)       = 0) OR v.HubCastingMaterialTypeId           IN (SELECT Value FROM @HubCastingMaterialTypeIds          ))
      AND (((SELECT COUNT(Value)      FROM @HubAssemblyTypeIds)              = 0) OR v.HubAssemblyTypeId                  IN (SELECT Value FROM @HubAssemblyTypeIds                 ))
      AND ((SELECT COUNT(Token)
            FROM @SearchTokens
            WHERE ((LEN(Token) > 0) AND ((CAST(CHARINDEX(Token, th.ThreadDesignation) AS INT) > 0)))) = (SELECT COUNT(Token) FROM @SearchTokens WHERE LEN(Token) > 0))
```

This is invalid T-SQL syntax. How can I express the *WHERE ... IIF(cond, Field NOT IN ...)* idea to achieve the same effect?

```
IIF(@ExcludeProvidedValues = 1,
        v.AxleStudThreadId NOT IN (SELECT Value FROM @AxleStudThreadIds),
        v.AxleStudThreadId IN (SELECT Value FROM @AxleStudThreadIds))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
OR IIF(@ExcludeProvidedValues=1, v.AxleStudThreadId NOT IN (SELECT Value FROM @AxleStudThreadIds), 1)
```

With:

```
1 = Case when @ExcludeProvidedValues=1 and v.AxleStudThreadId NOT IN (SELECT Value FROM @AxleStudThreadIds) then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't pose the problem correctly. Instead of 1 for the false condition, I meant to have a IN (SELECT Value...) statement to counteract the NOT IN (SELECT Value...) statement in the true condition. I found another way.

Comment: I corrected the question to clarify this oversight.

Answer (score 0):

The following clause does the trick

```
  AND (
       ((SELECT COUNT(Value) FROM @AxleStudThreadIds) = 0)
    OR ((@ExcludeProvidedValues = 0) AND v.AxleStudThreadId IN (SELECT Value FROM @AxleStudThreadIds))
    OR ((@ExcludeProvidedValues = 1) AND v.AxleStudThreadId NOT IN (SELECT Value FROM @AxleStudThreadIds))
  )
```

Here's the complete complete UDF definition:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [Aftermarket].[ft_Filter_V41_HubAssembly_AxleStudThreads_DEV] (
    @SearchTokens                    dbo.SearchTokenTableType      READONLY,
    @AftermarketHubAssemblyNumbers   dbo.ConMetPartNumberTableType READONLY,
    @TruckCompartmentIds             dbo.IntegerTableType          READONLY,
    @TruckMakeIds                    dbo.IntegerTableType          READONLY,
    @AxleNameIds                     dbo.IntegerTableType          READONLY,
    @GrossAxleWeightRatingRangeIds   dbo.IntegerTableType          READONLY,
    @AxleStudThreadIds               dbo.IntegerTableType          READONLY,
    @WheelMaterialStudLengthClassIds dbo.IntegerTableType          READONLY,
    @HubCastingMaterialTypeIds       dbo.IntegerTableType          READONLY,
    @HubAssemblyTypeIds              dbo.IntegerTableType          READONLY,
    @ExcludeProvidedValues BIT = 1
)
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN
    SELECT DISTINCT v.AxleStudThreadId AS Id,
    CASE v.AxleStudThreadId WHEN 0 THEN N'—' ELSE th.ThreadDesignation END AS Designation,
    bt.DiameterValue AS DiameterInch,
    CASE v.AxleStudThreadId WHEN 0 THEN N'—'
                            WHEN 6 THEN N'3/4'
                            WHEN 8 THEN N'5/8'
                            ELSE th.ThreadDesignation
                            END AS NominalDiameter
    FROM Aftermarket.vFilters_V3_HubAssemblies AS v
    JOIN Stud.Threads AS th ON v.AxleStudThreadId = th.Id
    JOIN Stud.BaseThreads AS bt ON th.BaseThreadId = bt.Id
    WHERE (((SELECT COUNT(PartNumber) FROM @AftermarketHubAssemblyNumbers)   = 0) OR v.HubAssemblyNumber                  IN (SELECT PartNumber FROM @AftermarketHubAssemblyNumbers ))
      AND (((SELECT COUNT(Value)      FROM @TruckCompartmentIds)             = 0) OR v.TruckCompartmentId                 IN (SELECT Value FROM @TruckCompartmentIds                ))
      AND (((SELECT COUNT(Value)      FROM @TruckMakeIds)                    = 0) OR v.TruckMakeId                        IN (SELECT Value FROM @TruckMakeIds                       ))
      AND (((SELECT COUNT(Value)      FROM @AxleNameIds)                     = 0) OR v.AxleNameId                         IN (SELECT Value FROM @AxleNameIds                        ))
      AND (((SELECT COUNT(Value)      FROM @GrossAxleWeightRatingRangeIds)   = 0) OR v.GawrRangeId                        IN (SELECT Value FROM @GrossAxleWeightRatingRangeIds      ))

      AND (
           ((SELECT COUNT(Value) FROM @AxleStudThreadIds) = 0)
        OR ((@ExcludeProvidedValues = 0) AND v.AxleStudThreadId IN (SELECT Value FROM @AxleStudThreadIds))
        OR ((@ExcludeProvidedValues = 1) AND v.AxleStudThreadId NOT IN (SELECT Value FROM @AxleStudThreadIds))
      )

      AND (((SELECT COUNT(Value)      FROM @WheelMaterialStudLengthClassIds) = 0) OR v.WheelMaterialStudLengthClassId     IN (SELECT Value FROM @WheelMaterialStudLengthClassIds    ))
      AND (((SELECT COUNT(Value)      FROM @HubCastingMaterialTypeIds)       = 0) OR v.HubCastingMaterialTypeId           IN (SELECT Value FROM @HubCastingMaterialTypeIds          ))
      AND (((SELECT COUNT(Value)      FROM @HubAssemblyTypeIds)              = 0) OR v.HubAssemblyTypeId                  IN (SELECT Value FROM @HubAssemblyTypeIds                 ))
      AND ((SELECT COUNT(Token)
            FROM @SearchTokens
            WHERE ((LEN(Token) > 0) AND ((CAST(CHARINDEX(Token, th.ThreadDesignation) AS INT) > 0)))) = (SELECT COUNT(Token) FROM @SearchTokens WHERE LEN(Token) > 0))
```